# Chasing NPC in roblox, stopping when player touch specified part

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to create chasing npc, that starts walking behind player when he touches part named "StrtChase", I also want the npc to stop chasing player and walk towards part named "NpcStartPos", when player touches part named "StopChase"

I tried using ChatGpt and Haddock (free version) but it didn't give me what i expected

Comment: You can use the build in pathfinding service to move the NPC towards the player. Next, enable the pathfinding script when player touches the startChase part and disable it when they touch the stopChase part.